# Pandas: Group by with MultiColumn

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with multiColumns. It is quite large, so here is some information:

```
In [73]: test.shape
Out[73]: (83, 82573)
```

Here's the first rows/columns

```
first                    senator      words                                    \
second                           000003198s 000s 000th 001st 002nd 00a 0157h7   
(property, partyCode)                                                           
200                     sessions          0    0     0     0     0   0      0   
200                       shelby          1    0     0     0     0   0      0   
200                    murkowski          0    1     0     0     0   0      0   
200                      stevens          0    1     0     0     0   0      0   
200                          kyl          0    0     0     0     0   0      0
```

Now I would like to group by index, and aggregate the numbers each specific word was said. I tried:

```
In [88]: test.groupby(test.index)['words'].sum()
Out[88]: 
(property, partyCode)
100    1016.583333
200    1476.333333
Name: words, dtype: float64
```

Which sums over the wrong axis. Usage of `agg()` did not help. How would I get my desired output?

#### Desired Output:

```
                         000003198s 000s 000th 001st 002nd 00a 0157h7 
(property, partyCode)
100    1016.583333                0    0     0     0     0   0      0
200    1476.333333                1    2     0     0     0   0      0
```

#### More Data on Structure:

How I get to my data frame: I take this one

```
first     senator      words                                                 \
second            000003198s 000s 000th 001st 002nd 00a 0157h7 1000s 1000th   
0        sessions          0    0     0     0     0   0      0     0      0   
1          shelby          0    0     0     0     0   0      0     0      0   
2       murkowski          0    0     0     0     0   0      0     0      0   
3         stevens          0    0     0     0     0   0      0     0      0   
4             kyl          0    0     0     0     0   0      0     0      0
```

It also has the following (multi-) column:

```
In [132]: df['property', 'partyCode'].head()
Out[132]: 
0    200
1    200
2    200
3    200
4    200
```

And then I set

```
test = df.set_index(('property', 'partyCode'))
```

Comment: Mmmmm you sure? Looks right... Can you provide an example of desired outcome?

Comment: @FirebladeDan I've added desired output

Comment: What is `df.columns`? And `df.index` ?

Comment: @jezrael is there any way I can output `head()` or something from columns? It's way too large to be shown

Comment: Ok, I have problem reproduced your `df`. Columns are first and second rows?

Comment: @jezrael Indeed they are, with `names=['first', 'second']`, if it matters.

Comment: I'm still confused by your table structure. Can you just provide header and row values.(property,partyCode) messing me up

Comment: @FirebladeDan I've added some more data. In the multi-column structure, I have `['property']['partycode']` as multi-layered column, which I then set as index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index).sum()
#remove first level of multiindex in columns
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
print df2
second                 000003198s  000s  000th  001st  002nd  00a  0157h7
(property, partyCode)                                                    
100                             0     0      0      0      1    0       0
200                             1     0      0      1      0    0       1

#does not work for me
df1 =  df.groupby(df.index)['words'].sum()
print df1
     (property, partyCode)
100                      1
200                      3

print pd.concat([df1['words'], df2], axis=1)
     (property, partyCode)  000003198s  000s  000th  001st  002nd  00a  0157h7
100                      1           0     0      0      0      1    0       0
200                      3           1     0      0      1      0    0       1
```

EDIT:  `df1 =  df.groupby(df.index)['words'].sum()` doesnt work for me.

For me work double [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index).sum().sum(axis=1)
df1.name = 'words'
print df1
(property, partyCode)
100    1
200    3
Name: words, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! `df2` is exactly what I need. It appears you can't select the top-layer of multi column when you `groupby`, but then selecting it afterwards is fine